# How to play chess online using Knights?

Tags: 18.04, games, webserver, chess

Recently I installed the chess game software Knights for ubuntu. I'm trying to play online using a server (a feature according to the website: https://kde.org/applications/games/org.kde.knights) But I got the following issue:[image]

How can I able that menu?

**Edit 1.** 
I run the command: *hostnamectl* and got this:

```
Static hostname: marin-Aspire-E5-521
     Icon name: computer-laptop
       Chassis: laptop
    Machine ID: 403b41e1f87f499cb8b39aea045edc36
       Boot ID: 84fabc4a665c48c4bd4f6ae1b525e488 
    Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-74-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
```

The version of Knight is:

[image]

I installed it using the Ubuntu Software aplication. (I don't know how to use snap or deb packages)

**Edit 2.**
Sorry for the snipped image. Here the complete window:[image]

**Edit 3.**

Those are my options for computer engine, there is not a chess server.

[image]

I cannot enable the chess server option.

**Edit 4.**

I already have the XBoard and UCI protocols installed.

[image]

**Edit 5.**

[image]

Comment: Please provide OS/release details. Also the version of `knights` installed (or how installed; eg. snap version? (https://snapcraft.io/knights) or deb package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=knights))

Comment: You have snipped a little bit too much away from the left of your image :). First player should be you and second player should be 'Chess Server'. Can you access this option with player 2?

Comment: @guiverc The information requested is now in the main post in Edit 1.

Comment: @andrew.46 There is a new picture in Edit 2.

Comment: @JoséMarín Thanks! On my system instead of selecting the 'Computer engine' option for Player 2 I selected 'Chess Server' and then a dialogue box opened with details for signing up with freechess.org...

Comment: @andrew.46. That's the problem, I cannot select the option 'Chess Server' for player 2.

Comment: @Rinzwind I think I already have the XBoard protocol installed.

Comment: @JoséMarín I have just created a fresh VM with Ubuntu 18.04 and online Knights game worked out of the box. However I see that the standard Knights for Ubuntu 18.04 is actually 2.5.0 while you are trying to get Knights 2.6.0 running, Looks like the newer versions (with a new developer) are tracked from Ubuntu 19.04  and onwards: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=knights&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all My suspicion is that have installed a package that does not fit with Ubuntu 18.04 and the situation would be rectified with the standard, repository version of Knights.

Comment: And your kernel version is wrong for 18.04 as well?

Comment: @andrew.46 so... the soultion will be uninstall the verison 2.6.0 and install again via standard repository? but I installed this verison with the Ubuntu Software aplication. There is a screenshot of the information of the program in the main post on Edit 5. And what do you mean by wrong kernel version? That is the information of my machine. I installed ubuntu, and that was set by "default".

Comment: @JoséMarín OIC: you have the snap version of knights which has broken chess online for me as well. Problem is found!! If you run the following 2 commands all should be resolved: First: `sudo snap remove knights` and then `sudo apt-get install knights` and then hopefully all will be well :)

Comment: @andrew.46 I typed those commands and now I have the 2.5.0 version, it looks older, but with this version the chess server for player 2 is available. Thank you. Post the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @JoséMarín Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the 'snap' version of Knights which installs Knights 2.6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. I can certainly confirm on my own system that there is an issue with this version where it *does not allow online play with freechess.org*.

The repository version is a little older at 2.5.0 but it works out of the box with online play. To return to this older version first remove the snap version:

```
sudo snap remove knights
```

and then install the older repository version:

```
sudo apt-get install knights
```

Now you can successfully play chess with other players on freechess.org! It might be material for another question as to why the newer version fails...